# Getting error in restemplate post call

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am getting the below error when using the resttemplate for making a post request to a spring based rest service

Below is my code:

```
 public void getData(String ip){
        try{
            RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

            rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());/////Error Occurs are this line 
            rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            String uri=new String("http://"+ip+":8080/pcap");
            Pcap_params pcap=new Pcap_params();
            pcap.setFlow_id("786");
            pcap.setIp_a("192.65.78.22");
            pcap.setPort_a("8080");
            pcap.setRegex("%ab");
            pcap.setTime_range("22-23");
            ResponseEntity rep=rt.postForEntity(uri, pcap, ResponseEntity.class);

        System.out.println("hi");
}
```

And below error Im getting

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Note im using

```
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
```

which has nothing to with the use  of `org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException` so really confused why error is occuring. I tried to add the library also but then it gave error of no class `dif:objectmapper` not found.

Comment: Are you using maven or ant? Or just you set the library jars?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,issue was with the version of the spring ,updated pom.xml as below

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` is just wrapper for `Jackson` library. If you don't have it on classparth, you get this error.

Solution if you are using Maven would be to include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @lubockrnac 
it still gives the same error ,added the above in pom.xml 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)